# Curvefitting for power law function y= a(x^b)+c

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, power-law

I am new to MATLAB, and I am trying to fit a power law through a dataset. I have been trying to use isqcurvefit function, but I am unsure how to proceed as the instructions found through Google are too convoluted for a beginner. I would like to derive the values b and c from the equation y = a(x^b)+c, and any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What was the documentation and what was the first thing you didn't understand? You are asking for a duplicate of such a page.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`lsqcurvefit`](https://mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html) to fit a non linear curve through measured data points in *least-square sense* as follows:

```
% constant parameters
a = 1; % set the value of a
% initial guesses for fitted parameters
b_guess = 1; % provide an initial guess for b
c_guess = 0; % provide an initial guess for c
% Definition of the fitted function
f = @(x, xdata) a*(xdata.^x(1))+x(2);
% generate example data for the x and y data to fit (this should be replaced with your real measured data)
xdata = 1:10;
ydata = f([2 3], xdata); % create data with b=2 and c=3
% fit the data with the desired function
x = lsqcurvefit(f,[b_guess c_guess],xdata,ydata); 
%result of the fit, i.e. the fitted parameters
b = x(1)
c = x(2)
```